# AMPL: how to make a resriction between expressions of variables?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, ampl

My problem is the following: I have to solve a linear programming problem about blends using AMPL. I could solve it by making a file with both the model and data inside, however what I should do is make a more generalized model separated from data.
My trouble is with the restrictions between variables - I don't know how do I generalize those and later reflect in the data.
For example, I have the following restrictions:

```
subject to restriction1:
    Xc2 + Xd2 <= Xa2 + Xb2;
subject to restriction2:
    Xc3 + Xd3 >= 0.5*(Xa3 + Xb3);
```

where Xc2, Xd2, Xa2, etc., are all variables.
I can't find any tutorial explaining this. Hope you can help me a bit...

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to separate the model from the data? Or do you want to separate restrictions and put them into different files? Separating the model from the data is easy and I can tell you how to do that. However, I have the impression that you want to do something else...

Comment: I want to separate the model from the data. I don't have that many restrictions to put them into different files. I'll appreciate it a lot if you can just tell me how to do the former.

Answer (score 2):

You normally want to separate the model, the parameters and the commands as they can vary independently. Here is an example:

Put this into the model file **examp.mod**

```
var x1 >= 0;
var x2 >= 0;

param c;

maximize z:
  x1 + x2;

s.t.
constraint_1:
  x1 + x2 <= c;
```

Put the actual values of the parameters into a separate data file **examp.dat**

```
data;

param c := 1;
```

Put all the commands into another file **examp.run**

```
#option solver "enter your solve name here and remove the #";

solve;

display x1, x2;
```

You can run this from the command line as follows (depends on your operating system and settings)

ampl examp.mod examp.dat examp.run

This prints

```
LP_SOLVE 4.0.1.0: optimal, objective 1
1 simplex iterations
x1 = 0
x2 = 1
```

on my machine.

If I am not mistaken the .mod, .dat and .run extensions are not necessary, you can have .txt as well.

If you have further questions, I recommend the freely downloadable AMPL book, directly from the AMPL developers:

http://www.ampl.com/BOOK/download.html

In particular, see *1.4 The linear programming model in AMPL*, on page 10, they show how to separate the model from the data.

---

**UPDATE**  I am still not 100% sure if I understand the question correctly. I assume you wish to enable / disable constraints depending on some scenario.

In the example below, there is a single model, and the data decides on the actual constraints that are included in the final model passed to the solver. In the example, I enable `constraint_a` but I exclude `constraint_b`. The model is unpleasant to read and write beacuse you have to write your model accordingly.

You can inspect the generated model with the command `solexpand _scon;`. Also see the other options that should be enabled.

```
var x1 >= 0;
var x2 >= 0;

param is_a_enabled;
param is_b_enabled;

maximize z:
  x1 + x2;

s.t.
constraint_a:
  is_a_enabled*(x1+x2-3) <= 0; # x1+x2<=3 if enabled, 0<=0 otherwise

constraint_b:
  is_b_enabled*(x1+2*x2-4)<=0; # x1+2*x2<=4 if enabled, 0<=0 otherwise

# you can put everything below into a separate file
data;

param is_a_enabled := 1;
param is_b_enabled := 0;

option presolve 10;
option substout 1;
option show_stats 1;

solve;

print "Constraints finally passed to the solver are:";
solexpand _scon;

print "Solution:";   
display x1, x2;
```

This generated the following output

```
Presolve eliminates 1 constraint.
Adjusted problem:
2 variables, all linear
1 constraint, all linear; 2 nonzeros
        1 inequality constraint
1 linear objective; 2 nonzeros.

LP_SOLVE 4.0.1.0: optimal, objective 3
1 simplex iterations
Constraints finally passed to the solver are:
subject to constraint_a:
        x1 + x2 <= 3;

Solution:

x1 = 0
x2 = 3
```

Comment: Ali, thank you, but I know all of that. My problem is that I have a constraint like "Xc2 + Xd2 <= Xa2 + Xb2" where all of those are variables (declared previously as var Xc2 >= 0; etc.). There are no parameters with defined numeric value in this constraint. Also, the number of variables might be subjected to the data. Here is an example: we have ingredients A, B, C, D and recipes for various cocktails. For a cocktail 1, the recipe is "(A+B)<=50%, C>=10%, (C+D)<=(A+B)" which leads me to a constraint composed of variables. This is trivial to write directly, but how do I generalize this model?

Comment: @user1760764 This is why I asked you what you wanted to do. You cannot do this directly in AMPL. However, you can do it indirectly, and then the presolve eliminates the inactive constraints. Unfortunately, I have to leave now, maybe in a a couple of hours I will be back and give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: I have much more than a couple of hours for this and I would like just to have an answer to this generally, since it seems to be hard to find an answer. I'll appreciate it very much if you'll explain it to me.

Comment: Thank you, Ali. That doesn't answer my question, but after reading it, it actually helped me a lot to clarify some concepts. Basically, what I wanted to do is to create a generalized model for blends, but the problem I have is that each new blend may have a new set of constraints that don't resemble at all the constraints for other blends (they are different not just by parameters, but by the expression). So right now I think that there is no other way, but to change the model in order to add a new type of blend with new constraints, because we can't put those constrains as data.

Comment: @user1760764 Well, if you still have questions then please post another question, with a detailed example.